# Is it possible to use the BBPOS WisePOS E and allow customers to choose donation amount?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want a device that allows people to choose the amount they would like to donate to our charity using stripe.

Is the BBPOS WisePOS E reader only meant for accepting payments via another device/application, or is it possible to allow the "donater" to use just the reader to choose an amount and process payments directly on the reader?

My use case:

I want to accept donations and just let people choose the amount they want to donate directly on the BBPOS WisePOS E reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stripe readers including BBPOS WisePOS E do not support on-reader donation.

Currently, donation is supported via Payment Links and Checkout Session that donors can choose the amount to pay:

- Payment Links (re-usable): https://support.stripe.com/questions/how-to-accept-donations-through-stripe
- Checkout Session (one-time): https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pay-what-you-want